# app-route issue in polymer 2 displaying data

Tags: polymer

When I route using app-route, the url changes but the data is displayed on the previous page itself. When I click on Quiz Page the data is displayed in the page from where it is clicked and not from the assessment page. How can I fix this?

my-data.html

```
        <app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path>
        </app-location>
        <app-route route="{{route}}" 
        pattern="/:page" 
        data="{{routeData}}" 
        tail="{{selectedItems}}">
        </app-route>

        <iron-selector selected="{{routeData.page}}" attr-for-selected="my-data">
            <a my-data="assessment" href="assessment/[[_computeId(selectedItem)]]">Quiz Page</a> 

        </iron-selector>

        <my-assessment name="assessment"
            ssessment = "{{selectedItems}}"></my-assessment>
```

my-assessment.html

```
<app-route
        route="{{ssessment}}"
        pattern="/:user_id"
        data="{{routeData}}"></app-route>
        <iron-ajax
            id="requestRepos"
            url="{{_computeId(routeData.user_id)}}"
            handle-as="json"
            last-response="{{repos}}">
        </iron-ajax>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{repos}}">
                <my-quiz repos= "{{repos}}"></my-quiz>
        </template>
```

Comment: Please explain more. I could not understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I issue was that I commented out Assessment.js from my main app page which did not render it. Now its working.